# OT extension question about base-OT

Tags: oblivious-transfer

Recently, I am learning the [Oblivious Transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblivious_transfer) (OT) Protocol. I have some questions about the OT extension. In [ALSZ13](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/552.pdf), we know that $m\times OT_l$ can be reduced to $\kappa\times OT_\kappa$, where $\kappa$ is a security parameter, $l$ is secret's bit length. So my question is:

- How can I implement $\kappa\times OT_\kappa$? Is it run $OT_\kappa^1$ protocol $\kappa$ times? If yes, is $OT_\kappa^1$ same to [NP01](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/365411.365502) Protocol 3.1 says that $OT_1^N$?

Comment: I've edited your question. You can see how to use the links in a better way. You are lucky since [Prof. Lindell](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/25354/yehuda-lindell) is a user, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I implement $\kappa\times OT_\kappa$?

You pick your favourite public-key based OT protocol. Usually these will allow you to input a choice bit and learn exactly one out of two $r$ bit values in return.

Then you input two random $r$-bit values into that protocol and use the $\kappa$-bit hashes as output. This is your $OT_\kappa$ protocol.

Next, you execute $\kappa$ (e.g. 128) instances of that protocol *in parallel* with independently random choice bits. This is what is usually done for these OT-extension protocols.

As for building a $OT_\kappa$ from $OT_1$s, you can indeed run $\kappa$ such protocols in parallel with the same choice bit (which is only immediately secure in a semi-honest model).

Comment: Much thanks. :)

Comment: Hello, I have another question about base OT phase, see [ALSZ13](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/552.pdf) Protocol 5.2, is it just need to compute only $\kappa$ times to get the hash input relation between $S$ and $R$? Or can we reuse this relation for different OT extension phase?